# How to allow extra spaces in html lists

Tags: html, css

I want to have extra spaces inside list items but the browser is removing them when rendering.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Row    1</li>
  <li>Row    2</li>
</ul>
```

I want the rendered list to keep the extra spaces for each item.

Comment: Do you really have list data? It's beginning to look tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set white-space: pre on your li elements

```
li { white-space: pre}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space for more info on white-space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `span` and `margin`.

```css
.extra {
  margin-right: 3em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="extra">Row</span><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span class="extra">Row</span><span>2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap one of your word in tag for example `span` and set margin for it

Comment: why you give me negative?
solution work fine https://jsfiddle.net/ut6zujof/

Answer (score -2):

The Title says **spaces** not extra space.

You can write

```
&nbsp
```

to place a space charater.

```
<li>Row&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp2</li>
```